# Where can I find the native source code of android API of camera?

Tags: android, camera, android-source, 3gp

In order to make the streaming and saving data of the recording at the same time, I would like to use the output of Mediarecorder which an Api in Android to record a video.

However, when I save the data that produced by `recorder.setOutputFile`, It is not a legal 3gp format.

Therefore, I would like to study the source code of `camera.start()` and `camera.stop()` to make the output file become readable.

Does someone can tell me where can I find the native code of these member?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The android sources are here:
https://android.googlesource.com.

This posting might also be informative:
https://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/8995288acaa30018?fwc=1

MediaRecorder itself:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/media/java/android/media/MediaRecorder.java

Answer (score 1):

Here is the link, please try it:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Camera